Need Help Resolving Error When Downloading Settlement Report
I'm a beginner in Magento, and I've been tasked by my boss to resolve an issue we're facing when trying to download a settlement report. The error message we’re getting is:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65NOIN6B.png
It seems to occur in the ConvertToCsv.php file when generating the CSV file. I'm not sure how to approach this issue since I’m still learning Magento.
Could someone guide me on how to fix this error? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

the error message is pretty explicit by itself, may be share the code ?

Thank you for the quick response!
Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the PHP files. I'm working with MySQL Workbench and the Magento admin panel only.
